# Como hacer un array de memoria dinamica de strings?

Tags: array, c, string

Estoy tratando de hacer un array dinamico en dos dimensiones que almacene strings, pero al poner los valores, estos se sobre escriben de forma extraña.

```
    int r=3, c=4, len=0; 
    char *ptr, **arr; 
    int count = 0,i,j,k; 

    len = sizeof(char *) * r + sizeof(char) * c * r; 
    arr = (char **)malloc(len); 

    /* ptr is now pointing to the first element in of 2D array */
    ptr = (char *)(arr + r); 

    /* for loop to point rows pointer to appropriate location in 2D array */
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++) 
        arr[i] = (ptr + c * i); 

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) 
            strcpy(&arr[i][j],"HI"); /* OR *(*(arr+i)+j) = ++count */

    printf("%s \n", &arr[0][0]);


    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("%s ", &arr[i][j]);
    }   
    printf("\n");
    }
```

El output me aparece algo asi: HHHHI HHHI HHI, cuando quiero que me aparezca solo HI en todas las casillas.
Creo que tiene que ver con la forma en la que estoy describiendo mi array, pero n estoy segura de cual es el problema

Comment: `printf("%s \n", &arr[0][0]);`, no debería ser con los valores del for?

Comment: es mas recomendable el uso de "realloc"

Answer (score 2):

> Estoy tratando de hacer un array dinamico en dos dimensiones...

No es cierto. No has creado ningún array de dos dimensiones, has creado uno de una dimensión:

```
len = sizeof(char *) * r + sizeof(char) * c * r;
```

Con tres filas (`r`) y cuatro columnas (`c`), la memoria que estás reservando es de 36 bytes si tus punteros son de 8 bytes<sup>1</sup> que dado que lo conviertes a puntero a puntero:

```
arr = (char **)malloc(len);
```

Se te queda en un total de 36 / 8 = 4,5 elementos, lo cuál es obviamente incorrecto (no puedes tener medios elementos).

En caso de que tus punteros sean de 4 bytes<sup>2</sup>, la memoria que estás reservando es de 24 bytes lo que te deja un total de 24 / 4 = 6 elementos, lo cuál también es incorrecto pues presuntamente pediste tener tres filas y cuatro columnas (y ninguno de esos números es 6).

---

Lo que estás haciendo es crear un array de una dimensión y tratarlo como si fuese de dos dimensiones, pero no te va a funcionar. La memoria que pides tiene este aspecto<sup>3</sup>:

```
       ---------------------------------- arr ----------------------------------
byte   | 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|
índice |     0     |     1     |     2     |     3     |     4     |     5     |
tipo   |  char **  |  char **  |  char **  |  char **  |  char **  |  char **  |
```

Es decir: cada uno de los elementos es un puntero a puntero anexo en memoria y sin conocimiento alguno de las dimensiones, le asignas posiciones de manera incorrecta:

```
ptr = (char *)(arr + r);
```

Para empezar, apuntas a la posición 4 de `arr` reinterpredo desde punteros a punteros a caracter (`char **`) como punteros a caracter (`char *`):

```
       ---------------------------------- arr ----------------------------------
byte   | 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|
índice |     0     |     1     |     2     |     3     |     4     |     5     |
       |           |           |           | (arr + r) |           |           |
```

Haces que los tres primeros elementos de `arr` apunten mal:

```
for(i = 0; i < r; i++) 
    arr[i] = (ptr + c * i);
```

```
         ---------------------------------- arr ----------------------------------
byte     | 0| 1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|...>
índice   |     0     |     1     |     2     |     3     |     4     |     5     |...>
posición |           |           |           | (ptr + 0) |           |           |           | (ptr + 4) |           |           |           | (ptr + 8) |
valor    | (ptr + 0) | (ptr + 4) | (ptr + 8) |
```

Como puedes ver, no tiene ni pies ni cabeza, además de desconocer las dimensiones, el compilador no puede saber cuántas posiciones debe saltar para avanzar el índice; en memoria anexa, para llegar a la columna X, fila Y (`arr[Y][X]`) debe seguir esta fórmula:

> Posición 1D = Y * columnas + X

Si ni siquiera sabe las columnas, no puede deducir la posición.

#### Propuesta: Array 1D como 2D.

Pide la memoria del array adecuadamente:

```
int r = 3, c = 4, len = r * c; 
char *ptr = (char *)malloc(len);
```

Si tienes tres filas y cuatro columnas, significa que tendrás 12 caracteres, ni más ni menos. Para escribir en la posición correspondiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    strcpy(ptr + i * c, "HI"); // Cada fila, está en la posición I * COLUMNAS
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kpp3yGyl6pA78tTx).

#### Propuesta: Array bidimensional real.

Pide la memoria adecuadamente:

```
int r = 3, c = 4;
char **ptr = (char **)malloc(r);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    ptr[i] = (char *)malloc(c);
    memset(ptr[i], 0, c);
}
```

Para escribir en la posición correspondiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    strcpy(ptr[i], "HI");
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BGZsq1l4PHdIKuoQ).

---

1. Como posiblemente sea el caso en arquitecturas de 64bits.
2. Como posiblemente sea el caso en arquitecturas de 32bits.
3. Uso el caso de 4 bytes por puntero.